# Obtaining Homeomorphisms from Family of Homeomorphisms on Closed Subspaces

Tags: general-topology

While making the following figure (notes for an algebraic topology course about the Euler characteristic) I needed an explicit homeomorphism from the unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ to the closed triangle defined by the convex hull of $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, and $(1,0)$.
[image]
I went about this by dividing the square up into wedges of the form
$(r,0)-(r,r)-(0,r)$ where $-$ denotes a straight line connecting the points. In addition, there is also the point $(0,0)$. This dividing process is shown below.
[image]
An explicit function for mapping the square into the triangle can be given by:
\begin{align}
t&=\frac{y-x+\textrm{max}\{x,y\}}{2}\\
f(x,y)&=(t, \textrm{max}\{x,y\}-t\}
\end{align}
I did not check that the resulting function is indeed a homeomorphism (seems to be intuitively) since my figure came out as I wanted, but this made me think of the following question. If $f_{\alpha}:\mathcal{U}_{\alpha}\rightarrow\mathcal{V}_{\alpha}$ are a family of homeomorphisms from a collection of mutually disjoint closed subsets of $X$ into mutually disjoint closed subsets of $Y$ (which cover their repsective spaces) and if the $\mathit{gluing}$ function $f:X\rightarrow{Y}$:
\begin{equation}
f(x)=f_{\alpha}(x)\quad{x}\in\mathcal{U}_{\alpha}
\end{equation}
is continuous, then is $f$ a homeomorphism? The answer is “not always”, as the following demonstrates. Take $X=[0,1)$ and $Y=\mathbb{S}^{1}$, let $f(x)=\exp(2\pi{i}x)$. Let $\mathcal{U}_{x}=\{x\}$ and $f_{x}=f|_{\{x\}}$. That is, the closed sets are just singletons, and the $f|_{\alpha}$ are just the restriction of $f$ to these points. This is a family of homeomorphisms which glue together to give us $f$, but $f$ is not a homeomorphism.

$\mathbf{Question}:$
Is there a reasonable set of requirements to impose such that given a family of homeomorphisms $f_{\alpha}:\mathcal{U}_{\alpha}\rightarrow\mathcal{V}_{\alpha}$ from subspaces of $X$ to subspaces of $Y$, we may glue this together to obtain a homeomorphism $f:X\rightarrow{Y}$.